Writing Hessenberg form of matrix fails with complex elements but succeds with real numbers
I'm writing a function in python to create the hessenberg for a square matrix. (Without using linalg obviously) and, despite working flawlessly for real numbers it fails for complex number.
I've looked up everything I can on this online, and I'm following the algorithm to a T so there shouldn't be any problem
The strangest things is that when i test the eighen values of the new matrix (that's not in hessenberg form) they are quite close to what they should be
Here is the function in it's current form (using linalg.norm for simplicity, in the future it'll be changed)
def Hessenberg(A):
    n = np.shape(A)[0]
    H = np.copy(A)
    Q = np.eye(n,dtype=complex)
    for k in range(n - 2):
        u = np.copy(H[k+1:, k])
        sign_x = np.array((-np.sign(u[0].real), -np.sign(u[0].imag)))
        sign_x /= np.linalg.norm(sign_x)
        u[0] = u[0] - (sign_x[0]+ 1j*sign_x[1]) * np.linalg.norm(u)
        u /= np.linalg.norm(u)
        
        H[k+1:, k:] -= 2 * np.outer(u, np.dot(u.conj().T, H[k+1:, k:]))
        H[:, k+1:] -= 2 * np.outer(np.dot(H[:, k+1:], u), u.conj().T)
        Q[k+1:, :] -= 2 * np.outer(u, np.dot(u.conj().T, Q[k+1:, :]))
    return H, Q.T 

The P matrix seems to be unitary, but when multiplying it properly with the original matrix it should give a hessenberg form, but it fails too, which leads me to believe my problem is in the calculation of u
I also tried about every possible norms, and it obviously makes things worse

You need to replace the transpose with the conjugate or hermitian transpose. In the complex the reflectors are based on the hermitian scalar product.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
